# Chrome bookmarks in folder - open all in new windows?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

In chrome (chromium running on Ubuntu 10.04 specifically) is there a way to open all bookmarks in a bookmark folder, each in their own new window?  I realize that I could just open them all in tabs, then drag each to its own window, but I'd rather not do that extra step for each window.  Is this possible?

**Update:**

Note, this is different from "open all bookmarks in tabs of a new window" which is what "open tabs in a new window" does.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most streamlined way and it's a bit sloppy, but it mostly works. You can edit the URL part of the bookmark with some javascript.

1. Right click on the bookmarks folder and choose bookmark manager
2. Right click on each of your bookmarks and choose edit
3. In the URL section put this code: `javascript:window.open("http://URL", "window name", "height=800, width=800, modal=yes, alwaysRaised=yes");`

You can change the window name and width/height as needed. It's also important to put the `http://` or `https://` before the url or it won't work. Now you can right click on the folder and click open all bookmarks and they will all open in new windows. I also have to point out that it will open a number of blank tabs equal to the number of bookmarks in the current window. Don't know why, but it's just one window you can close.

Comment: I was looking for a way to not only open every link in a new window but also to auto-resize- as I am monitoring multiple servers simultaneously. TY for this ! This should be marked as the answer even if its a hack, as it solves Chrome's shortsightedness in this matter. Need to see if I can position it too - I'm sure there is a way (Update=found it - top=0, left=960). Also sucks that Chrome allows itself to be minimized only so much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just install the extension [New Tab, New Window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-new-window/dndlcbaomdoggooaficldplkcmkfpgff) *(opens all new tabs as new windows)*,
2. Then middle click the bookmark folder *(to open all contained bookmarks)*.

--

Leave the extension disabled for normal tab behavior. Simply enable it when opening bookmarks folder.

If you want a quick & easy way to enable/disable the extension, use [Extensity](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensity/jjmflmamggggndanpgfnpelongoepncg) *(adds a quick toggle button for extensions)*.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on one of the folders in your bookmark bar.  You will notice 3 options:
    Open all bookmarks
    Open all bookmarks in new window
    Open all bookmarks in incognito window

Comment: -1 That opens all the bookmarks into *a* new window IE if there are 16 bookmarks in the folder, it will open a new window with 16 tabs.  I want 16 new windows.